# aggregating/joining data by week with differing week lengths (5days vs 7days)

Tags: r

I have two data frames that I am trying to merge/aggregate together. The first data frame consists of price level information and a date. The dates range from Monday - Sunday so, 7 days a week.

The second data frame contains share price information, share price and a date, from Monday - Friday, so 5 days of the week.

The `min` of the date columns is the following;

```
> min(price_info$WEEKref)
[1] "2008-01-14 CET"
> min(share_info$date)
[1] "2008-01-11"
```

The `max` of the date columns are;

```
> max(price_info$WEEKref)
[1] "2012-12-31 CET"
> max(share_info$date)
[1] "2012-12-28"
```

which are close but not matching, which is because the `price_info` data frame has 7 days a week and the `share_info` has 5 days of trading activity.

What I am trying to do is to join both data frame together so that the weeks match.

I have tried using a `mutate` function from `dplyr` with `lubridate` such as; `mutate(wk = week(WEEKref))` and `mutate(yr = year(WEEKref))` but I am still having some problems with the 7 days of the week vs the 5 days of the week.

The 7 days of the week comes from purchase information which can be made available on Sat/Sun however the share price information can only be obtained from Monday - Friday.

Data 1:

```
    price_info <- structure(list(DOLLARS = c(107.92, 12.59, 41.93, 15.87, 11.98, 
67.41, 64.71, 107.88, 206.85, 21.96, 131.78, 27.98, 9.9, 16.99, 
23.38, 69.95, 19.96, 9.18, 35.95, 90.91, 19.98, 67.95, 18.36, 
8.79, 13.99, 7.29, 6.45, 95.94, 23.37, 7.98, 5.6, 62.37, 328.65, 
252.64, 8.99, 37.47, 83.94, 55.96, 90.86, 560.49, 16.58, 17.97, 
8.99, 36.45, 15.98, 29.91, 16.17, 79.92, 125.86, 12.99, 10.78, 
11.98, 19.9, 11.78, 50.94, 139.8, 128.73, 24.38, 9.99, 14.9, 
36.28, 89.94, 9.39, 70.74, 456.01, 182.38, 8.36, 23.07, 18.57, 
10.78, 42.32, 133.4, 17.99, 62.76, 11.78, 89.91, 5.79, 29.95, 
13.98, 45.43, 83.96, 137.48, 27.45, 119.98, 13.45, 16.45, 26.37, 
65.94, 93.9, 32.98, 21.98, 223, 17.98, 29.96, 120.89, 38.97, 
38.43, 8.49, 29.98, 28.47, 43.74, 103.87, 11.88, 149.9, 29.9, 
43.08, 28.95, 87.92, 98.31, 23.98, 38.39, 13.18, 36.33, 12.78, 
5.69, 9.99, 53.91, 19.18, 13.86, 26.46, 5.98, 34.14, 13.5, 17.97, 
264.76, 83.93, 233.19, 62.91, 118.68, 155.88, 35.97, 11.95, 39.16, 
10.98, 11.38, 49.45, 24.87, 54.32, 769.08, 66.95, 61.45, 356.79, 
19.08, 3.99, 39.9, 127.92, 48.95, 15.38, 9.58, 12.78, 167.84, 
81.59, 37.73, 14.98, 45.63, 41.96, 986.53, 4.99, 59.96, 38.94, 
96.73, 39.16, 11, 602.3, 7.49, 129.9, 13.98, 8.58, 33.96, 11.18, 
26.97, 8.98, 11.38, 12.49, 153.89, 6.99, 12.58, 71.39, 47.96, 
11.97, 7.99, 58.03, 35.97, 38.43, 47.96, 6.98, 29.16, 6.49, 5.19, 
29.98, 9.16, 70.9, 5.99, 21.98, 39.13, 143.91, 1.89, 82.92, 11.98, 
11.61, 19.35, 6.59, 10.36, 107.92, 59.94, 41.97, 20.07, 67.96, 
39.92, 27.96, 10.99, 15.12, 14.76, 111.92, 19.95, 19.47, 43.95, 
42.21, 9.79, 104.93, 17.49, 27.98, 672.49, 29.67, 14.98, 19.97, 
287.84, 48.95, 27.45, 6.99, 2.79, 341.81, 4.29, 17.97, 44.76, 
155.76, 49.76, 44.73, 14.99, 21.45, 16.99, 95.94, 40.47, 57.45, 
51.92, 13.98, 92.9, 15.99, 25.98, 5.99, 5.29, 181.87, 62.01, 
87.89, 17.92, 48.93, 89.94, 139.93, 11.99, 8.49, 37.45, 16.77, 
51.92, 51.15, 49.95, 61.96, 32.58, 9.38, 170.39, 1444, 39.98, 
11.99, 25.74, 19.47, 29.95, 23.96, 28.45, 5.29, 9.78, 23.97, 
391.72, 20.19, 16.99, 22.47, 195.72, 17.99, 123.31, 139.9, 23.34, 
35.98, 65.91, 48.93, 129.9, 143.91, 53.97, 644.57, 29.98, 30.32, 
99.95, 7.79, 17.97, 13.98, 29.97, 8.37, 3.18, 25.95, 29.96, 5.29, 
9.16, 18.98, 97.9, 31.96, 29.97, 151.85, 26.97, 389.74, 27.96, 
368.7, 14.29, 11.58, 65.94, 7.99, 124.9, 20.98, 65.94, 119.95, 
27.92, 44.97, 7.39, 1.99, 49.41, 8.39, 8.69, 56.72, 17.98, 1.65, 
90.93, 20.98, 128.28, 175.84, 90.72, 25.96, 21.17, 60.39, 51.55, 
16.98, 44.97, 84.95, 146.9, 47.92, 20.97, 637.71, 179.8, 75.92, 
11.96, 7.98, 23.9, 39.92, 9.73, 21.96, 181.39, 47.97, 9.96, 262.15, 
5.49, 12.38, 13.99, 48.51, 338.76, 29.97, 91.92, 1941.84, 25.96, 
12.99, 8.99, 47.96, 8.99, 9.99, 15.99, 17.58, 28.17, 51.88, 12.38, 
91.92, 87.43, 12.99, 73.43, 64.95, 23.97, 29.97, 19.47, 96.93, 
13.99, 73.97, 148.41, 13.99, 74.69, 164.85, 23.96, 63.95, 27.92, 
23.96, 14.98, 63.92, 6.98, 9.45, 9.58, 11.87, 80.43, 49.98, 137.94, 
15.29, 64.9, 5.49, 79.4, 155.88, 17.59, 24.95, 98.91, 23.16, 
179.82, 22.77, 13.98, 29.58, 39.8, 71.92, 59.95, 56.34, 27.38, 
12.49, 74.95, 35.75, 21.99, 15.18, 3.38, 97.64, 13.52, 197.91, 
26.45, 3.18, 168.87, 91.04, 23.96, 119.8, 234.96, 55.46, 8.49, 
13.98, 29.97, 26.36, 13.65, 35.94, 87.95, 9.49, 7.49, 40.46, 
59.9, 17.98, 44.95, 18.39, 21.98, 32.97, 44.97, 10.9, 14.99, 
7.49, 7.49, 53.91, 58.95, 14.97, 125.82, 15.98, 13.17, 71.91, 
503.79, 113.28, 5.79, 6.99, 30.95, 35.91, 1.39, 24.98, 6.59, 
197.28, 52.44, 5.49, 29.85, 9.95, 42.4, 19.95, 89.94, 64.95, 
13.49, 6.95, 46.95, 55.46, 111.39, 118.93, 12.98, 20.28, 459.54, 
40.96, 39.83, 54.45, 18.98, 69.93, 65.9, 16.74, 32.98, 179.85, 
83.48, 83.94, 28.45, 6.99, 28.45, 18.58, 13.99, 13.78, 11.99, 
319.68, 69.95, 43.56, 11.83, 83.94, 13.99, 12.53, 83.88, 40.47, 
16.47, 10.39, 47.8, 6.29, 21.98, 101.31, 28.95, 5.98, 5.99, 21.89, 
10.58, 64.95, 35.37, 3.99, 111.84, 23.97, 73.89, 5.5, 194.9, 
361.81, 16.99, 49.14, 10.99, 16.47, 54.95, 131.88, 11.94, 3.18, 
23.67, 41.97, 54, 137.77, 321.96, 22.33, 7.99, 4.98, 10.99, 5.49, 
13.98, 10.49, 10.49, 11.98, 12.99, 6.59, 20.97, 7.95, 14.99, 
43.98, 6.99, 80.43, 2.58, 14.98, 8.29, 53.97, 29.98, 134.86, 
25.98, 22.47, 22.99, 21.97, 35.94, 10.99, 5.79, 109.89, 12.99, 
33.44, 10.98, 29.97, 11.59, 41.93, 203.83, 12.78, 33.98, 115.39, 
75.96, 10.49, 319.8, 33.96, 59.92, 17.97, 10.99, 47.97, 65.94, 
29.95, 32.97, 25.96, 41.16, 59.7, 32.98, 41.94, 283.36, 10.98, 
125.93, 15.58, 11.12, 46.94, 11.99, 55.56, 11.98, 209.86, 69.93, 
314.79, 7.49, 57.8, 6.49, 41.97, 71.94, 92.94, 6.99, 421.43, 
14.69, 13.98, 301.07, 15.98, 21.87, 35.16, 22.47, 10.99, 14.99, 
6.49, 102.24, 32.97, 13.5, 16.49, 24.76, 141.57, 9.99, 21.98, 
79.92, 11.59, 5.56, 131.88, 17.97, 51.24, 19.77, 6.18, 10.16, 
8.38, 17.97, 40.47, 635.62, 55.46, 127.92, 26.91, 65.97, 38.43, 
7.99, 23.96, 142.85, 41.94, 6.99, 26.82, 23.98, 28.47, 8.49, 
11.34, 15.66, 19.38, 28.98, 7.29, 111.14, 79.96, 56.34, 12.99, 
6.49, 15.95, 19.74, 17.48, 7.99, 62.32, 22.58, 14.34, 71.92, 
29.95, 37.8, 5.59, 17.98, 31.45, 33.98, 15.19, 20.37, 23.94, 
115.35, 13.99, 47.94, 14.98, 239.85, 15.98, 16.98, 181.73, 65.97, 
415.68, 74.97, 38.97, 55.93, 34.47, 67.41, 19.98, 161.72, 134.85, 
63.96, 8.99, 27.96, 6.99, 22.99, 51.73, 15.99, 83.61, 39.98, 
37.8, 12.98, 23.07, 7.79, 23.98, 95.22, 38.97, 15.12, 14.98, 
35.98, 89.94, 40.42, 43.74, 32.88, 78.27, 33.84, 10.99, 3.98, 
59.95, 1.89, 119.61, 3.99, 32.45, 64.95, 13.99, 4.29, 181.48, 
20.99, 244.35, 55.92, 8.49, 8.79, 59.43, 108.68, 12.99, 7.49, 
19.99, 31.47, 147.92, 9.36, 25.11, 99.16, 18.99, 5.99, 29.97, 
13.99, 49.77, 7.45, 13.99, 15.9, 129.9, 57.28, 27.98, 26.98, 
71.91, 315.5, 6.99, 6.99, 5.58, 22.41, 29.95, 239.76, 32.97, 
16.98, 3.87, 186.87, 35.82, 7.99, 13.58, 215.82, 227.4, 20.79, 
25.96, 17.99, 7.69, 23.98, 7.49, 94.95, 239.82, 1.89, 23.98, 
102.06, 33.87, 29.95, 18.99, 37.98, 51.92, 254.83, 6.49, 13.47, 
38.97, 31.41, 57.87, 21.98, 95.94, 125.91, 12.29, 119.92, 6.39, 
23.98, 14.99, 17.98, 47.97, 69.9, 57.51, 45.96, 71.88, 53.91, 
39.98, 12.29, 34.7, 6.99, 23.98, 13.58, 11.94, 43.98, 16.49, 
5.39, 10.95, 29.96, 9.38, 139.8, 102.83, 27.98, 239.7, 31.98, 
152.46, 11.99, 87.45, 9.39, 16.38, 6.99, 7.99, 41.97, 44.95, 
8.99, 12.49, 17.97, 125.93, 7.99, 2.19, 7.49, 35.97, 77.94, 95.88, 
25.98, 7.79, 59.95, 168.92, 1.99, 47.97, 229.77, 21.98, 9.39, 
6.99, 22.47, 29.98, 241.98, 159.9, 31.96, 25.58, 31.47, 9.98, 
19.98, 29.88, 34.95, 10.45, 125.93, 97.9, 69.19, 33.56, 6.79, 
31.79, 13.98, 33.67, 164.88, 22.47, 13.99, 279.83, 34.47, 31.96, 
41.97, 15.99, 59.95, 5.97, 95.92, 11.98, 27.96, 31.58, 7.96, 
17.98, 26.99, 7.49, 2.59, 223.89, 247.35, 14.99, 49.95, 85.74, 
26.76, 83.88, 35.97, 42.45, 71.96, 243.64, 515.57, 21.96, 14.97, 
25.02, 13.12, 27.98, 29.96, 82.19, 63.92, 6.99, 26.37, 31.98, 
27.96, 7.89, 41.94, 31.96, 75.88, 61.96, 188.36, 14.59, 37.73, 
25.96, 103.92, 71.94, 12.99, 21.98, 111.92, 31.74, 9.99, 77.87, 
95.83, 27.92, 6.49, 7.99, 129.87, 19.49, 12.45, 19.99, 83.16, 
7.49, 138.58, 208.89, 7.19, 8.76, 13.98, 28.94, 32.97, 111.92, 
17.98, 275.77, 34.93, 27.98, 13.98, 11.99, 15.98, 13.58, 11.3, 
13.16), WEEKref = structure(c(1199660400, 1199660400, 1199660400, 
1199660400, 1199660400, 1200265200, 1200265200, 1200265200, 1200870000, 
1200870000, 1201474800, 1202079600, 1202079600, 1202684400, 1202684400, 
1203289200, 1203289200, 1203289200, 1203289200, 1203289200, 1203894000, 
1203894000, 1203894000, 1204498800, 1204498800, 1205103600, 1205103600, 
1205103600, 1205103600, 1205708400, 1205708400, 1205708400, 1205708400, 
1205708400, 1206313200, 1206313200, 1206313200, 1206313200, 1206313200, 
1206914400, 1206914400, 1206914400, 1206914400, 1206914400, 1206914400, 
1207519200, 1208124000, 1208728800, 1208728800, 1208728800, 1208728800, 
1208728800, 1208728800, 1208728800, 1209333600, 1209333600, 1209333600, 
1209333600, 1209938400, 1209938400, 1209938400, 1210543200, 1210543200, 
1210543200, 1210543200, 1210543200, 1211148000, 1211148000, 1211148000, 
1211148000, 1211752800, 1211752800, 1212357600, 1212357600, 1212357600, 
1212962400, 1212962400, 1212962400, 1212962400, 1213567200, 1213567200, 
1213567200, 1213567200, 1214172000, 1214776800, 1214776800, 1214776800, 
1214776800, 1214776800, 1214776800, 1214776800, 1214776800, 1215381600, 
1215381600, 1215381600, 1215986400, 1215986400, 1216591200, 1216591200, 
1216591200, 1216591200, 1216591200, 1217196000, 1217196000, 1217196000, 
1217196000, 1217800800, 1217800800, 1217800800, 1217800800, 1217800800, 
1217800800, 1218405600, 1218405600, 1218405600, 1218405600, 1218405600, 
1218405600, 1218405600, 1218405600, 1219010400, 1219010400, 1219010400, 
1219010400, 1219010400, 1219010400, 1219010400, 1219010400, 1219615200, 
1219615200, 1219615200, 1219615200, 1220220000, 1220220000, 1220824800, 
1220824800, 1220824800, 1221429600, 1221429600, 1221429600, 1221429600, 
1222639200, 1222639200, 1222639200, 1223244000, 1223244000, 1223244000, 
1223244000, 1223848800, 1223848800, 1223848800, 1223848800, 1224453600, 
1224453600, 1224453600, 1224453600, 1225062000, 1225062000, 1225062000, 
1225062000, 1225666800, 1225666800, 1225666800, 1225666800, 1225666800, 
1226271600, 1226271600, 1226271600, 1226271600, 1226271600, 1226876400, 
1226876400, 1227481200, 1227481200, 1228086000, 1228086000, 1228690800, 
1228690800, 1229295600, 1229295600, 1229295600, 1229900400, 1229900400, 
1230505200, 1230505200, 1230505200, 1230505200, 1231110000, 1231110000, 
1231714800, 1231714800, 1231714800, 1232319600, 1232924400, 1232924400, 
1232924400, 1232924400, 1232924400, 1232924400, 1232924400, 1232924400, 
1232924400, 1232924400, 1233529200, 1233529200, 1233529200, 1233529200, 
1233529200, 1234134000, 1234134000, 1234738800, 1234738800, 1234738800, 
1234738800, 1235343600, 1235343600, 1235343600, 1235343600, 1235343600, 
1235948400, 1235948400, 1235948400, 1236553200, 1236553200, 1236553200, 
1237158000, 1237158000, 1237762800, 1237762800, 1238364000, 1238364000, 
1238364000, 1238968800, 1238968800, 1238968800, 1238968800, 1238968800, 
1238968800, 1239573600, 1240178400, 1240178400, 1240178400, 1240178400, 
1240783200, 1240783200, 1240783200, 1241388000, 1241388000, 1241992800, 
1241992800, 1241992800, 1241992800, 1241992800, 1242597600, 1242597600, 
1242597600, 1242597600, 1242597600, 1242597600, 1242597600, 1243202400, 
1243202400, 1243202400, 1243202400, 1243202400, 1243202400, 1243807200, 
1243807200, 1243807200, 1243807200, 1244412000, 1244412000, 1244412000, 
1244412000, 1244412000, 1245016800, 1245016800, 1245016800, 1245621600, 
1245621600, 1245621600, 1245621600, 1245621600, 1245621600, 1246226400, 
1246226400, 1246226400, 1246226400, 1246226400, 1246226400, 1246226400, 
1246226400, 1246226400, 1246226400, 1246831200, 1246831200, 1246831200, 
1246831200, 1246831200, 1247436000, 1247436000, 1247436000, 1247436000, 
1247436000, 1248040800, 1248040800, 1248040800, 1248040800, 1248040800, 
1248040800, 1248040800, 1248040800, 1248645600, 1248645600, 1249250400, 
1249250400, 1249250400, 1249250400, 1249855200, 1249855200, 1249855200, 
1250460000, 1250460000, 1250460000, 1251064800, 1251064800, 1251064800, 
1251064800, 1252274400, 1252274400, 1252274400, 1252274400, 1252274400, 
1252274400, 1252879200, 1252879200, 1252879200, 1252879200, 1252879200, 
1252879200, 1252879200, 1253484000, 1253484000, 1253484000, 1253484000, 
1253484000, 1254088800, 1254088800, 1254088800, 1254088800, 1254693600, 
1254693600, 1254693600, 1255298400, 1255298400, 1255298400, 1255903200, 
1255903200, 1255903200, 1255903200, 1255903200, 1256511600, 1256511600, 
1256511600, 1257116400, 1257721200, 1257721200, 1257721200, 1257721200, 
1257721200, 1258326000, 1258326000, 1258326000, 1258930800, 1258930800, 
1258930800, 1258930800, 1258930800, 1258930800, 1259535600, 1259535600, 
1260140400, 1260745200, 1260745200, 1261350000, 1261350000, 1261350000, 
1261350000, 1261954800, 1261954800, 1261954800, 1262559600, 1262559600, 
1262559600, 1262559600, 1262559600, 1262559600, 1263164400, 1263164400, 
1263164400, 1263769200, 1263769200, 1263769200, 1263769200, 1263769200, 
1263769200, 1264374000, 1264374000, 1264978800, 1264978800, 1264978800, 
1264978800, 1265583600, 1265583600, 1265583600, 1265583600, 1265583600, 
1266188400, 1266188400, 1266793200, 1266793200, 1266793200, 1266793200, 
1266793200, 1267398000, 1267398000, 1267398000, 1267398000, 1267398000, 
1267398000, 1268002800, 1268002800, 1268002800, 1268002800, 1268002800, 
1268607600, 1268607600, 1268607600, 1268607600, 1269212400, 1269212400, 
1269212400, 1269212400, 1269212400, 1269212400, 1269813600, 1269813600, 
1269813600, 1269813600, 1269813600, 1269813600, 1269813600, 1269813600, 
1270418400, 1270418400, 1271023200, 1271023200, 1271023200, 1271023200, 
1271628000, 1271628000, 1272232800, 1272232800, 1272232800, 1272837600, 
1272837600, 1272837600, 1272837600, 1273442400, 1273442400, 1273442400, 
1273442400, 1273442400, 1273442400, 1273442400, 1274047200, 1274047200, 
1274652000, 1274652000, 1274652000, 1274652000, 1274652000, 1274652000, 
1275256800, 1275256800, 1275256800, 1275256800, 1275256800, 1275861600, 
1275861600, 1275861600, 1275861600, 1275861600, 1275861600, 1275861600, 
1275861600, 1276466400, 1276466400, 1276466400, 1276466400, 1276466400, 
1277071200, 1277071200, 1277071200, 1277676000, 1277676000, 1277676000, 
1277676000, 1278280800, 1278280800, 1278280800, 1278280800, 1278885600, 
1278885600, 1278885600, 1278885600, 1278885600, 1278885600, 1278885600, 
1278885600, 1278885600, 1279490400, 1279490400, 1279490400, 1279490400, 
1279490400, 1280095200, 1280095200, 1280700000, 1280700000, 1280700000, 
1281304800, 1281304800, 1281304800, 1281304800, 1281304800, 1281909600, 
1281909600, 1281909600, 1282514400, 1282514400, 1282514400, 1282514400, 
1283119200, 1283119200, 1283119200, 1283119200, 1283119200, 1283119200, 
1283724000, 1283724000, 1283724000, 1283724000, 1283724000, 1283724000, 
1284328800, 1284328800, 1284328800, 1284933600, 1284933600, 1284933600, 
1285538400, 1285538400, 1285538400, 1285538400, 1285538400, 1286143200, 
1286143200, 1286143200, 1286748000, 1286748000, 1286748000, 1287352800, 
1287352800, 1287352800, 1287352800, 1287957600, 1287957600, 1287957600, 
1288566000, 1288566000, 1289170800, 1289170800, 1289170800, 1289170800, 
1289170800, 1289170800, 1289775600, 1289775600, 1289775600, 1289775600, 
1290380400, 1290380400, 1290985200, 1290985200, 1290985200, 1290985200, 
1291590000, 1291590000, 1291590000, 1291590000, 1291590000, 1292194800, 
1292194800, 1292194800, 1292194800, 1292799600, 1292799600, 1292799600, 
1292799600, 1292799600, 1292799600, 1293404400, 1293404400, 1293404400, 
1293404400, 1293404400, 1293404400, 1294009200, 1294614000, 1294614000, 
1294614000, 1295218800, 1295218800, 1295218800, 1295218800, 1295218800, 
1295823600, 1296428400, 1296428400, 1296428400, 1296428400, 1296428400, 
1296428400, 1297033200, 1297638000, 1297638000, 1297638000, 1297638000, 
1298242800, 1298242800, 1298242800, 1298242800, 1298847600, 1298847600, 
1298847600, 1298847600, 1299452400, 1299452400, 1299452400, 1300057200, 
1300057200, 1300057200, 1300057200, 1300662000, 1300662000, 1301263200, 
1301868000, 1301868000, 1302472800, 1302472800, 1302472800, 1302472800, 
1302472800, 1303077600, 1303077600, 1303077600, 1303077600, 1303682400, 
1303682400, 1304287200, 1304287200, 1304287200, 1304287200, 1304892000, 
1304892000, 1304892000, 1304892000, 1305496800, 1305496800, 1305496800, 
1305496800, 1306101600, 1306101600, 1306101600, 1306101600, 1306706400, 
1306706400, 1307311200, 1307311200, 1307311200, 1307311200, 1307311200, 
1307916000, 1307916000, 1307916000, 1307916000, 1307916000, 1308520800, 
1308520800, 1309125600, 1309125600, 1309125600, 1309730400, 1309730400, 
1309730400, 1309730400, 1309730400, 1309730400, 1310335200, 1310335200, 
1310335200, 1310335200, 1310335200, 1310940000, 1310940000, 1311544800, 
1311544800, 1312149600, 1312149600, 1312149600, 1312149600, 1312149600, 
1312754400, 1312754400, 1312754400, 1312754400, 1312754400, 1313359200, 
1313964000, 1313964000, 1313964000, 1314568800, 1314568800, 1314568800, 
1314568800, 1315173600, 1315173600, 1315173600, 1315173600, 1315173600, 
1315778400, 1315778400, 1315778400, 1315778400, 1315778400, 1316383200, 
1316383200, 1316383200, 1316988000, 1316988000, 1317592800, 1317592800, 
1318197600, 1318197600, 1318197600, 1318802400, 1318802400, 1318802400, 
1318802400, 1319407200, 1319407200, 1320015600, 1320015600, 1320015600, 
1320015600, 1320015600, 1320620400, 1320620400, 1321225200, 1321225200, 
1321225200, 1321225200, 1321225200, 1321225200, 1321225200, 1321225200, 
1321225200, 1321225200, 1321830000, 1321830000, 1322434800, 1323039600, 
1323039600, 1323039600, 1323039600, 1323039600, 1323644400, 1323644400, 
1323644400, 1323644400, 1323644400, 1323644400, 1323644400, 1324249200, 
1324249200, 1324249200, 1324249200, 1324249200, 1324854000, 1324854000, 
1324854000, 1324854000, 1325458800, 1325458800, 1325458800, 1325458800, 
1326063600, 1326063600, 1326063600, 1326668400, 1326668400, 1326668400, 
1326668400, 1326668400, 1326668400, 1327273200, 1327273200, 1327273200, 
1327878000, 1327878000, 1327878000, 1327878000, 1327878000, 1328482800, 
1328482800, 1328482800, 1328482800, 1329087600, 1329087600, 1329087600, 
1329087600, 1329087600, 1329692400, 1329692400, 1329692400, 1329692400, 
1329692400, 1330297200, 1330297200, 1330297200, 1330297200, 1330297200, 
1330297200, 1330297200, 1330297200, 1330297200, 1330902000, 1330902000, 
1330902000, 1330902000, 1330902000, 1331506800, 1331506800, 1331506800, 
1331506800, 1331506800, 1332111600, 1332111600, 1332111600, 1332712800, 
1332712800, 1332712800, 1332712800, 1333317600, 1333317600, 1333317600, 
1333317600, 1334527200, 1334527200, 1334527200, 1334527200, 1335132000, 
1335132000, 1335132000, 1335132000, 1335132000, 1335132000, 1335736800, 
1335736800, 1335736800, 1335736800, 1335736800, 1335736800, 1335736800, 
1336341600, 1336341600, 1336341600, 1336341600, 1336946400, 1336946400, 
1336946400, 1337551200, 1337551200, 1337551200, 1337551200, 1337551200, 
1338156000, 1338156000, 1338760800, 1338760800, 1338760800, 1339365600, 
1339365600, 1339365600, 1339365600, 1339970400, 1339970400, 1340575200, 
1340575200, 1340575200, 1341180000, 1341180000, 1341180000, 1341784800, 
1341784800, 1341784800, 1342389600, 1342389600, 1342994400, 1342994400, 
1342994400, 1342994400, 1343599200, 1343599200, 1343599200, 1343599200, 
1344204000, 1344204000, 1344204000, 1344204000, 1344808800, 1344808800, 
1344808800, 1345413600, 1346018400, 1346018400, 1346018400, 1346623200, 
1346623200, 1346623200, 1346623200, 1347228000, 1347228000, 1347228000, 
1347228000, 1347228000, 1347832800, 1347832800, 1347832800, 1347832800, 
1348437600, 1348437600, 1349042400, 1349042400, 1349042400, 1349042400, 
1349042400, 1349042400, 1349647200, 1349647200, 1349647200, 1349647200, 
1350252000, 1350252000, 1350252000, 1350252000, 1350856800, 1350856800, 
1350856800, 1350856800, 1350856800, 1351465200, 1351465200, 1351465200, 
1352070000, 1352070000, 1352070000, 1352070000, 1352070000, 1352674800, 
1352674800, 1352674800, 1352674800, 1352674800, 1353279600, 1353279600, 
1353279600, 1353884400, 1353884400, 1354489200, 1354489200, 1354489200, 
1354489200, 1354489200, 1355094000, 1355094000, 1355698800, 1355698800, 
1355698800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1000L))
```

Data 2:

```
share_info <- structure(list(date = structure(c(13889, 13896, 13903, 13910, 
13917, 13924, 13931, 13938, 13945, 13952, 13958, 13966, 13973, 
13980, 13987, 13994, 14001, 14008, 14015, 14022, 14029, 14036, 
14043, 14050, 14057, 14064, 14071, 14078, 14085, 14092, 14099, 
14106, 14113, 14120, 14127, 14134, 14141, 14148, 14155, 14162, 
14169, 14176, 14183, 14190, 14197, 14204, 14211, 14218, 14225, 
14232, 14237, 14246, 14253, 14260, 14267, 14274, 14281, 14288, 
14295, 14302, 14309, 14316, 14323, 14330, 14337, 14343, 14351, 
14358, 14364, 14372, 14379, 14386, 14393, 14400, 14407, 14414, 
14421, 14428, 14435, 14442, 14449, 14456, 14463, 14470, 14477, 
14484, 14491, 14498, 14505, 14512, 14519, 14526, 14533, 14540, 
14547, 14554, 14561, 14568, 14575, 14582, 14589, 14596, 14602, 
14609, 14617, 14624, 14631, 14638, 14645, 14652, 14659, 14666, 
14673, 14680, 14687, 14694, 14700, 14708, 14715, 14722, 14729, 
14736, 14743, 14750, 14757, 14764, 14771, 14778, 14785, 14792, 
14799, 14806, 14813, 14820, 14827, 14834, 14841, 14848, 14855, 
14862, 14869, 14876, 14883, 14890, 14897, 14904, 14911, 14918, 
14925, 14932, 14939, 14946, 14953, 14960, 14967, 14973, 14981, 
14988, 14995, 15002, 15009, 15016, 15023, 15030, 15037, 15044, 
15051, 15058, 15065, 15072, 15079, 15085, 15093, 15100, 15107, 
15114, 15121, 15128, 15135, 15142, 15149, 15156, 15163, 15170, 
15177, 15184, 15191, 15198, 15205, 15212, 15219, 15226, 15233, 
15240, 15247, 15254, 15261, 15268, 15275, 15282, 15289, 15296, 
15303, 15310, 15317, 15324, 15331, 15338, 15345, 15352, 15359, 
15366, 15373, 15380, 15387, 15394, 15401, 15408, 15415, 15422, 
15429, 15435, 15443, 15450, 15457, 15464, 15471, 15478, 15485, 
15492, 15499, 15506, 15513, 15520, 15527, 15534, 15541, 15548, 
15555, 15562, 15569, 15576, 15583, 15590, 15597, 15604, 15611, 
15618, 15625, 15632, 15639, 15646, 15653, 15660, 15667, 15674, 
15681, 15688, 15695, 15702), class = "Date"), adjusted = c(24.747421, 
22.497637, 22.836473, 25.795502, 24.485403, 24.995857, 24.47637, 
27.1056, 26.224661, 26.631205, 25.623804, 24.910007, 25.799982, 
26.644787, 26.848055, 25.678005, 25.739576, 24.639721, 24.513144, 
23.788029, 24.138477, 23.014256, 24.055735, 23.165115, 21.48127, 
20.172163, 21.656496, 19.899628, 21.315849, 20.668577, 23.272152, 
23.846483, 22.113907, 23.072638, 23.058084, 23.564222, 22.474094, 
20.12351, 19.466503, 15.952772, 14.539044, 13.614408, 15.317719, 
14.979488, 13.886943, 10.025247, 10.03412, 9.847294, 10.995496, 
11.388611, 12.525135, 13.887408, 14.420643, 13.315253, 14.362259, 
15.498786, 15.958066, 15.592198, 16.051481, 16.970041, 14.681421, 
16.588604, 15.576628, 15.790699, 16.432917, 16.15657, 17.351479, 
17.514948, 18.374041, 19.552214, 18.988743, 19.236984, 19.504929, 
19.713776, 19.229105, 19.307913, 20.174797, 21.494829, 21.234766, 
21.526354, 22.022842, 21.999205, 21.817942, 21.408142, 23.208899, 
23.32711, 22.937016, 24.509232, 25.183033, 24.036385, 23.642344, 
25.33671, 26.416378, 26.648861, 25.222443, 25.557373, 26.455784, 
26.711908, 26.640984, 27.897966, 28.17379, 27.724586, 28.055584, 
28.682098, 27.830976, 27.582735, 27.235985, 28.489027, 26.849821, 
28.496906, 29.379555, 28.969753, 28.646639, 29.080082, 30.002136, 
29.580503, 29.533228, 30.333126, 28.95793, 29.036737, 29.150679, 
28.676779, 30.393166, 30.405113, 31.165739, 31.157778, 32.113533, 
32.854248, 31.982113, 30.88299, 32.822392, 32.726814, 33.411774, 
32.364422, 31.209545, 33.411774, 32.388309, 32.388309, 33.837879, 
34.244083, 33.690536, 34.403378, 33.933456, 35.044529, 35.625946, 
36.438347, 35.868874, 34.710014, 34.248062, 35.394981, 34.566654, 
34.419308, 34.606468, 34.483021, 34.845409, 34.327713, 34.793644, 
34.387444, 32.671062, 32.181229, 32.324596, 32.862213, 31.89052, 
31.870615, 33.05336, 32.710888, 30.998482, 32.511768, 33.097168, 
32.603359, 33.897617, 34.152485, 34.927811, 33.499866, 34.075912, 
34.538372, 33.284866, 32.96439, 32.226078, 32.453251, 31.76362, 
32.485706, 32.737213, 31.869093, 33.507977, 32.615517, 30.461426, 
31.126724, 30.428984, 30.145012, 31.130779, 30.566896, 30.546627, 
30.761627, 32.270702, 31.512108, 32.453251, 32.453251, 32.400517, 
32.04353, 34.927811, 34.749317, 34.647903, 36.11235, 35.864899, 
35.694515, 37.292839, 38.380024, 37.661999, 38.039265, 38.858711, 
37.808041, 39.702496, 39.382019, 40.363724, 39.941837, 41.069592, 
43.089802, 44.444729, 44.152653, 44.444729, 43.617168, 43.909245, 
44.78548, 45.684174, 46.372334, 46.47184, 44.266388, 45.335945, 
43.943039, 45.095505, 46.57962, 46.1236, 50.824677, 52.109806, 
52.234173, 52.980377, 54.265507, 55.044865, 54.597145, 54.56398, 
54.224049, 55.368217, 56.45435, 53.908981, 55.674995, 54.862461, 
57.557083, 55.658413, 54.713223, 54.671764, 53.900688, 54.083096, 
53.560753, 55.459427, 55.873985, 56.039803, 55.66671, 55.111202, 
54.52253)), row.names = c(NA, -260L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

EDIT1:

To clarify some point, the share price data was obtained using the following;

```
library(tidyquant)
    start_date <- "2008-01-07"
    end_date <- "2012-12-31"

        ABI <- tq_get("ABI.BR", 
                      get = "stock.prices", 
                      from = start_date,
                      to = end_date)
```

Which gives `1277` observations, I then used `tq_mutate` to convert to weekly data:

```
weeklyABI <- ABI %>%
  tq_transmute(select = adjusted, 
               mutate_fun = to.weekly)
```

where `share_info <- weeklyABI`

EDIT2: Added 1000 observations

Comment: You haven't given a rule for joining them. Just ignore the dates to don't match?

Comment: Looks like you have multiple instances of price_info within a single week.

Comment: I have added a little more info on how I obtained the `share_info`.

Comment: Regarding the `price_info` the original data frame has 20million observations where there are many purchases of a product during each week so multiple instances are expected, I did a random sample of the full data frame for StackExchange.

Comment: All very interesting, but .... you are not answering the q. What rule is to be used? Do you want all the lines from price_info and match share_info multiple times to those?

Comment: Aggregate? How? Take the mean? Looks like share_info only has one value per week while price_info has a variable number of values.

Comment: I am going through your answer now, but yes share_info has one value per week because I aggregated it from daily to weekly. The price_info has many values / sales per week. - I made an error in the original post, correcting now.

Comment: Update to prev response: Are you refering to the "rule for joining them?" - here I am trying to aggregate all the data by weeks, so I have weekly data for the price_info but I have daily data for the share_info. I tried to aggegate the share_info into weekly data (see edit). However the beginning weekly dates do not match with each other. When I aggregate the share_info into weeks I get the following start date; `> min(share_info$date)
[1] "2008-01-11"` but the price_info "weekly" data begins on `> min(price_info$WEEKref)
[1] "2008-01-14 CET"` and I cannot seem to align them.

Comment: It's tough getting the weeks to align. The `POSIXlt` format has a day of the week value, so you can figure out what the first Monday has a s a yday value. Or it looks like you found a week function in pkg-`lubridate`. Substitute that value for the one I calculated using modulo arithmetic. Decide what you want to do with end of year and beginning of the year.

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo division to construct a week marker and merge on those values. May want to check a calendar to see if any are needing to be offset:

```
share_info$week_n <- paste( format(share_info$date,"%Y"),  
                             sprintf( "%02i", as.POSIXlt(share_info$date, origin="1970-01-01")$yday %/% 7),
                             sep="_")
 str( share_info$week_n )
# chr [1:260] "2008_01" "2008_02" "2008_03" "2008_04" "2008_05" "2008_06" "2008_07" "2008_08" "2008_09" "2008_10" "2008_11" ...
 price_info$week_n <- paste( format(price_info$WEEKref,"%Y"),  
                             sprintf( "%02i", as.POSIXlt(price_info$WEEKre, origin="1970-01-01")$yday %/% 7),
                             sep="_")
str( price_info$week_n )
# chr [1:500] "2008_01" "2008_01" "2008_02" "2008_04" "2008_06" "2008_07" "2008_07" "2008_08" "2008_10" "2008_10" "2008_11" ...
agg.price <- aggregate(price_info$DOLLARS, price_info['week_n'], FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
agg.share <- aggregate(share_info$adjusted, share_info['week_n'], FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
head( merge( price_info, share_info, by="week_n"))
#-----------------------------------------------------------
   week_n DOLLARS             WEEKref       date adjusted
1 2008_01    3.69 2008-01-13 15:00:00 2008-01-11 24.74742
2 2008_01   17.98 2008-01-13 15:00:00 2008-01-11 24.74742
3 2008_02   15.00 2008-01-20 15:00:00 2008-01-18 22.49764
4 2008_04   63.48 2008-02-03 15:00:00 2008-02-01 25.79550
5 2008_06   24.90 2008-02-17 15:00:00 2008-02-15 24.99586
6 2008_07    2.69 2008-02-24 15:00:00 2008-02-22 24.47637
>
```

I  realized I needed to use `paste(year,week)` as the aggregate and merge indicator